# How to make a PATCH request using DJANGO REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am not very experience with Django REST framework and have been trying out many things  but can not make my PATCH request work.

I have a Model serializer. This is the same one I use to add a new entry and ideally I Would want to re-use when I update an entry.

```py
class TimeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TimeEntry
        fields = ('id', 'project', 'amount', 'description', 'date')

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        super(TimeSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = user

    def validate_project(self, attrs, source):
        """
        Check that the project is correct
        """
        .....

    def validate_amount(self, attrs, source):
        """
        Check the amount in valid
        """
        .....
```

I tried to use a class based view :

```py
class UserViewSet(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    """
    API endpoint that allows timeentries to be edited.
    """
    queryset = TimeEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer
```

My urls are:

```py
url(r'^api/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserViewSet.as_view(), name='timeentry_api_edit'),
```

My JS call is:

```js
var putData = { 'id': '51', 'description': "new desc" }
$.ajax({
    url: '/en/hours/api/edit/' + id + '/',
    type: "PATCH",
    data: putData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

In this case I would have wanted my description to be updated, but  I get errors that the fields are required(for 'project'and all the rest). The validation fails. If add to the AJAX call all the fields it still fails when it haves to retrieve the 'project'.

I tried also to make my own view:

```py
@api_view(['PATCH'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def edit_time(request):

    if request.method == 'PATCH':
        serializer = TimeSerializer(request.user, data=request.DATA, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            time_entry = serializer.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) 
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This did not work for partial update for the same reason(the validation for the fields were failing) and it did not work even if I've sent all the fields. It creates a new entry instead of editing the existing one.

I would like to re-use the same serializer and validations, but I am open to any other suggestions. 
Also, if someone has a piece of working code (ajax code-> api view-> serializer) would be great.

Comment: This is kind of an old problem but I'm curious to see what happens if you: (1) Changing the request type to POST and (2) adding a `_method` field with value `PATCH`. See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browser-enhancements). Django rest framework should take care of partial updates, so it should Just Work.

Comment: I changed to using PUT instead of PATCH and just send everything, because i had access to get all the data and it worked like that. I remember I also found out something and adapted my code. Maybe now it would work with PATCH. Sorry, i do not have more information. It was a while ago.

Comment: So can you post your working code? @Vlad

Comment: I made it work with PATCH some time ago, I'm digging through my old code to see what I did. I was using `angular-resource` and I remember having configured the update endpoint with PATCH.
Have you tried using `viewsets.ModelViewSet` instead of `generics.UpdateAPIView`?

Comment: @Rexford: If the code is the same (the class based version not functional one) and make a PUT it was working.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña Yes, now i updated my APIs and use viewsets.ModelViewSet or  specific mixins. It works much better but when i started it was harder to get my head around them. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 74):

```
class DetailView(APIView):
    def get_object(self, pk):
        return TestModel.objects.get(pk=pk)

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        testmodel_object = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = TestModelSerializer(testmodel_object, data=request.data, partial=True) # set partial=True to update a data partially
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(code=201, data=serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(code=400, data="wrong parameters")
```

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views)
You do not need to write the `partial_update` or overwrite the `update` method. Just use the `patch` method.

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen `APIView.patch()` used before nor mentioned anywhere in the docs. Do you use `patch` in production without any issue? And do you also still have a `put` in the view?

Comment: Yes, I use patch, delete, put methods in my work and it works fine.

Comment: `patch` method is first available in `UpdateAPIView`, and the only things it does is calling `self.partial_update(...)` link to DRF 3.5.3 source code https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.5.3/rest_framework/generics.py#L221

Comment: @ramwin How to call UpdateAPIView with parameters from a function please help thank you

Comment: @NikhilBhardwaj Don't ever do this. If you want to reuse your UpdateAPIView, you can encapsulation the code in your UpdateAPIView to an update_function, and call the function in you UpdateAPIView and other place where you need it.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that you have **"PATCH"** in **http_method_names**. Alternatively you can write it like this:

```
@property
def allowed_methods(self):
    """
    Return the list of allowed HTTP methods, uppercased.
    """
    self.http_method_names.append("patch")
    return [method.upper() for method in self.http_method_names
            if hasattr(self, method)]
```

As stated in [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates):

> By default, serializers must be passed values for all required fields or they will raise validation errors. You can use the partial argument in order to allow partial updates.

Override `update` method in your view:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = TimeSerializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(customer_id=customer, **serializer.validated_data)
    return Response(serializer.validated_data)
```

Or just override method `partial_update` in your view:

```
def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Serializer calls **update** method of **ModelSerializer**(see [sources](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L897)):

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    raise_errors_on_nested_writes('update', self, validated_data)

    # Simply set each attribute on the instance, and then save it.
    # Note that unlike `.create()` we don't need to treat many-to-many
    # relationships as being a special case. During updates we already
    # have an instance pk for the relationships to be associated with.
    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        setattr(instance, attr, value)
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

Update pushes the **validated_data** values to the given instance. Note that update should not assume all the fields are available. This helps to deal with partial updates (**PATCH** requests).

Comment: HI, I tried the solution mentioned above but it fails when there is a required field in the nested model but the data is missing in the patch request.

Comment: "Make sure that you have "PATCH" in http_method_names. " - where is that?

Comment: All views are inherited from `django.views.generic.base.View` class. This class has the parameter `http_method_names`.

Answer (score 7):

The `patch` method is worked for me using `viewset` in DRF. I'm changing you code:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TimeEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        user_instance = serializer.instance
        request = self.request
        serializer.save(**modified_attrs)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: This seems like the recommended way according to the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/), if you're using the UpdateModelMixin.  This will allow you to override the default behavior or add any actions before or after data is saved.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ModelViewSet` instead and override `perform_update` method from `UpdateModelMixin`

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TimeEntry.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TimeSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
        # you may also do additional things here
        # e.g.: signal other components about this update
```

That's it. Don't return anything in this method. `UpdateModelMixin` has implemented `update` method to return updated data as response for you and also clears out `_prefetched_objects_cache`. See the [source code here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/fb802c091084e2e02eade7813174b18178c1f3a3/rest_framework/mixins.py#L61-L84).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issues as well, I solved it redefining the get_serializer_method and adding custom logic to handle the partial update. Python 3

```
 class ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
     def get_serializer_class(self):
         if self.action == "partial_update":
             return PartialUpdateSerializer
```

Note: you may have to override the partial_update function on the serializer. Like so:

```
class PartialUpdateSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    def partial_update(self, instance, validated_data):
       *custom logic*
       return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another posiblity is to make the request by URL. For example, I have a model like this

```
      class Author(models.Model):
        FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        MiddleName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        LastName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices = GENDERS)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, default = 1, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='author_user')
        IsActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        class Meta:
          ordering = ['LastName']
```

And a view like this

```
      class Author(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Author.objects.all()
        serializer_class = AuthorSerializer
```

So can enter http://127.0.0.1:8000/author/ to get or post authors. If I want to make a PATCH request you can point to http://127.0.0.1:8000/author/ID_AUTHOR from your client. For example in angular2, you can have something like this

```
       patchRequest(item: any): Observable<Author> {
        return this.http.patch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/author/1', item);
       }
```

It suppose you have configured your CORS and you have the same model in back and front.
Hope it can be usefull.