# DRF nested serializer not able to updated nested data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using **Django 2.x** and **Django REST Framework**.

I have a nested serializer set.

```
class ListFieldSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ListField
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'field_type'
        ]


class LeadListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    list_fields = ListFieldSerializer(many=True, source='list_field')

    class Meta:
        model = LeadList
        fields = [
            'id',
            'lead_id',
            'name',

            'list_fields',
        ]

    @transaction.atomic
    def create(self, validated_data):
        list_fields = validated_data.pop('list_field', None)

        lead_list = self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data)

        if list_fields:
            # Create fields

            for field in list_fields:
                ListField.objects.create(
                    lead_list=lead_list,
                    **field
                )

        return lead_list

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        list_fields = validated_data.pop('list_field', None)

        if list_fields:
            list_fields_dict = dict((i.id, i) for i in instance.list_field.all())

            for field in list_fields:
                if 'id' in field:
                    # If exists id, remove from the dict and update
                    field_item = list_fields_dict.pop(field['id'])

                    field_item.name = field.get('name', field_item.name)
                    field_item.field_type = field.get('field_type', field_item.field_type)
                    field_item.is_required = field.get('is_required', field_item.is_required)
                    field_item.order = field.get('order', field_item.order)
                    field_item.save()

                else:
                    # Create a new object
                    ListField.objects.create(lead_list=instance, **field)

        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

This is working fine for **POST** request. But when I send **PATCH** request with the following data, the `id` field is not retrieved in the serializer `update()` method and instead of update, it is creating a new instance for the fields.

```
{
    "name":"New name",
    "list_fields": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "Email"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148039/how-to-make-a-patch-request-using-django-rest-framework/39071384](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148039/how-to-make-a-patch-request-using-django-rest-framework/39071384) Check This.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the ID field back to the validated data through the list serializer's `to_internal_value()` method.

Basically what this method does is get the value from the ID from the raw data and make sure it's included after validation is run.

```
def to_internal_value(self, data):
    # Add the read only field used for identifying the objects being updated
    # to the validated data.
    ret = super().to_internal_value(data)

    lookup_field_name = 'id'

    if self.context['request'].method in ('PUT', 'PATCH'):
        ret[lookup_field_name] = self.fields[lookup_field_name].get_value(data)
    return ret
```