# How to use patch with (from django.views.generic import View)

Tags: python, django, django-views

What patch method do I use while creating an API with the View , (`from django.views.generic import View`)

Suppose I have a class like this :

```
from django.views.generic import View
class ArticleView(View):

    def patch(self, request, article_id, *args, **kwargs):
        # How can I patch data here 
        pass

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a PATCH request using DJANGO REST framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148039/how-to-make-a-patch-request-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari I'm not sure that helps...this looks like a traditional view, not DRF.

Comment: Yes I don't need DRF , I want to use a traditional view

Comment: Ok you are looking for this i think https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch